# Java Generics - Iterating with upper bounded and lower bounded wildcards

Tags: java, generics

I have **2 Interfaces**:

`public interface Flash { public void flash(int level); }` and

`public interface SuperFlash extends Flash { public void flash(int level, boolean repeat); }`

Then I have a custom collection class which should hold any number of things implementing `Flash` or `SuperFlash`. The **class declaration** looks something like

`public class FlashyThings<? extends Flash>`.

So the class can hold instances of type `Flash` and its subtype(s).

Inside the class `FlashyThings`, I am using an **`ArrayList`** to hold all of these objects:

`private ArrayList<? extends Flash> things;`

So far so good, now, when I try to iterate over the collection, is there a way to know/infer the dynamic type of the objects without using `instanceof` (as in the next snippet)?

```
for (Flash f : this.things) {
    if (f instanceof SuperFlash) { // <-- :(
        // SuperFlash things
    } else {
        // Flash things
    }
}
```

***This is the upper bounded side of the medal, now to the lower bounded side***

To begin with, I had to change the **class declaration** to

`public class FlashyThings`

as lower bounded wildcards are not allowed in the class declaration. The **`ArrayList`** declaration now looks like:

`private ArrayList<? super SuperFlash> things;`

Now iterating over the collection becomes:

```
for (Object o : this.things) { // <-- :((
    // All things are of type Object which is *really* not cool
    if (o instanceof SuperFlash) { // <-- :(
        // SuperFlash things
    } else {
        // Flash things
    }
}
```

So I'm pretty much stuck where I began.

What would be the recommended way to iterate over such a construct? To summarise, what I want to achieve having is

- the interface hierarchy described at the very top
- the class `FlashyThings` being parameterisable
- iterating over the `ArrayList things`, taking into account the dynamic type of its contents (without having to do the `instanceof` check)

Comment: Do you want `FlashyThings` to **implement** `Flash` or **receive a type parameter** than extends `Flash`?

Comment: I want it to receive a type parameter that extends `Flash`

Comment: Then you can simply use `class FlashyThings<T extends Flash>`. But then `FlashyThings` **does not** implement `Flash`, you can't expect to store `FlashyThings` instances in a `List` which is for `Flash` instances.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to store `FlashyThings` instances in the `List`, I want to store `Flash` or `SuperFlash` instances and then iterate over this `List` (preferably without having to do the `instanceof` check)

Comment: Is it important that your list contain both Flash and SuperFlash as this is poor design practice. Better to maintain two separate lists inside your FlashyThings and create a unified list on demand when needed.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way around using the instanceOf given that at your end point you would want to use class specific function, which inturn presents you with having to distinguish between the two

Comment: @Dunes at runtime it will be either `Flash` or `SuperFlash`, but not both mixed, still the code needs to support both variants

Comment: @Dunes There is nothing wrong with having types of different implementations in the same collection. It is not bad design, who on earth told you that? Is is rather one of the defining features of all modern Object Oriented languages and is used extensively in many design patterns, most famously the Composite pattern. If you want to point out a design flaw it should be that SuperFlash extends Flash, seemingly without reason, and that they instead should implement the same interface.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke To clarify, it's bad design to have a list that holds different types that implement incompatible interfaces. The various objects in the collection should be able to treated the same and definitely not require an `instanceOf` check to decide how to treat the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create an abstract FlashyThing that does as much of the shared methods as possible in the abstract class, leaving only the stuff that is dependent on knowing you have a Flash or SuperFlash to the subclass. For example (publics and privates left out for brevity):

```
abstract class AbstractFlashyThing<F extends Flash> {

    List<F> flashes;

    AbstractFlashyThing() {
        flashes = new ArrayList<F>();
    }

    void doOperations() {
        for (F flash : flashes) {
            doOperation(flash);
        }
    }

    abstract void doOperation(F flash);

}
```

Note how the generic type `F` is used as a place holder wherever possible.

Example subclass

```
class SuperFlashyThing extends AbstractFlashyThing<SuperFlash> {
    @Override
    void doOperation(SuperFlash superFlash) {
        // do super flash stuff
    }
}
```

Subclass is a concrete implementation rather than a generic class, so its instatiation is as follows.

```
SuperFlashyThing thing = new SuperFlashyThing();
// as opposed to the following
SuperFlashyThing<SuperFlash> thing = new SuperFlashyThing<SuperFlash>();
```

Comment: Almost there, the construct works fine for the subclass `class FlashyThing<Flash> extends AbstractFlashyThing`, but not for the `SuperFlashyThing<SuperFlash>` where using `void doOperation(SuperFlash superFlash)` doesn't compile, but forces me to use `void doOperation(Flash superFlash)`

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add the correct class declaration for `SuperFlashyThing`. That's what I get for not actually compiling my code.

Comment: no worries & thanks very much, figured it out in the meantime myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't quite understand the problem, but why are you making everything so complicated, instead of just using polymorphism? This is what the Object Oriented Paradigm is designed to do. Example:

**Flash.java**

```
public class Flash {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Flash doSomething()");
    }
}
```

**SuperFlash.java**

```
public class SuperFlash extends Flash {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("SuperFlash doSomething()");
    }
}
```

**FlashyThings.java**

```
public class FlashyThings {
    private ArrayList<Flash> things = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Flash> getThings() {
        return things;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        for (Flash thing : things) {
            thing.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**ExampleMain.java**

```
public class ExampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flash first = new Flash();
        SuperFlash second = new SuperFlash();
        Flash third = new Flash();

        FlashyThings things = new FlashyThings();
        things.getThings().add(first);
        things.getThings().add(second);
        things.getThings().add(third);

        things.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand from the question Flash.doSomething() has one param while SuperFlash has two. And now depending on what is in the list the OP want's to call or another in unique manner. (but I dunno how;))

Comment: I get that, but what if `SuperFlash`'s `doSomething` requires an additional parameter? If the static type is `Flash` than it only has that type information. But you're probably tight in terms of overcomplicating things...

Comment: @tttthomasssss In that case I would create a common interface, with a method that defines all parameters, and then the Flash implementation can simply ignore the extra values, that it doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an `enum` ?

```
public enum FlashType
{
    Flash, SuperFlash;  
}
```

Add a method for checking the flash type of any object of type `Flash`:

```
public interface Flash 
{
    void flash(int level);
    FlashType getType();

}
```

Then iterate over `private ArrayList<? extends Flash> things;`

```
for (Flash f : this.things)
{
    if (f.getType() == FlashType.SuperFlash)
    {
     // SuperFlash things
    }
    else if (f.getType() == FlashType.Flash)
    {
      // Flash things
    }
}
```

or iterate over `ArrayList<? super SuperFlash> things;`

```
for (Object o : this.things) 
{

    final Flash f = (Flash)o;//this cannot failed: SuperFlash extends Flash

    if (f.getType() == FlashType.SuperFlash)
    {
     // SuperFlash things
    }
    else if (f.getType() == FlashType.Flash)
    {
      // Flash things
    }
}
```